# You have a string that consist only of digits. You need to find how many zero digits ("0") are at the beginning of the given string

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement

Our task is to count all the first zeros in the string of numbers, like `'2333'` should be counted as `0`and `'00980'` be `2` .

I have several questions regarding this.

1. So I came up with this solution:

```
def beginning_zeros(a: str) -> int:
    if map(lambda x: x!=0, a): 
        s=str(int(a))
        return len(a)-len(s)
   
    return len(a)
```

it works well for the non-all-zero string, but why it returns `len(a)-1` when it comes to all `'0'` string?

like `beginning_zeros('000')` should be `3`, but python count that as `2`

and 2. about this solution:

```
def beginning_zero(a: str) -> int:

    a_num = int(a)
    if not a_num: # case a as all zeros

        return len(a)

    return len(a) - len(str(a_num))
```

it works perfectly, why is that `not int(a)` to execute the all-zero string? Is zero not counted `int()`? or is there more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

`map(lambda x: x != 0, a)` returns map-object that's always `True`, and it goes straight into if-block, so

> it works well for the non-all-zero string, but why it returns len(a)-1 when it comes to all '0' string?

hehe, it's because `str(int('000'))` is still `'0'` and `len('0')` is 1.

Answer (score -1):

You just need a simple loop that examines the characters left to right as follows:

```
def leading_zeroes(s):
    r = 0
    for c in s:
        if c == '0':
            r += 1
        else:
            break
    return r
```